# Do multi-state of entangled particles exists?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, observers, superposition

I haven't taken any course in Quantum mechanics. But I felt "Quantum Entanglement" quite interesting. I recently read some articles on it. But I am not sure if I understood anything or satisfied with the theory. What I learnt recently is a particle is in superposition state unless observed. For example talking about spin of an electron, it spins in both counter clockwise and clockwise direction until observed. So when two electrons are entangled and we observe one of the particles then it suddenly be in one of the states by which we can predict about other entangled particle. What's confusing me is how can a particle be in multi state when unobserved. Could it not be that they are already in predetermined state? Could it not be that superposition state might not exist at all and it is just a conception made by people? I am thinking it in a more classical point of view. Could anyone explain me in layman term?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is known as a Local Hidden Variables theory, and those are [ruled out by violations of Bell inequalities](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48066/how-does-bells-theorem-rule-out-the-possibility-of-local-hidden-variables) as observed in a wide array of experiments. In short, the kind of model you're talking about imposes some bounds on the amount of certain types of correlation that can be observed between results of independent measurements of the two particles, and the experiments show that the observed correlations exceed those bounds.

For more details, see the multitude of previous questions about [Local Hidden Variables](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=local+hidden+variables) and [Bell inequalities](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=bell+inequalities) on this site.